# How to create slack's loading screen - ElectronJS

Tags: electron

Does anyone know how to create a separate loading screen with ElectronJS similar to how Slack does it with their's?

[image: ElectronJS Loading Screen]

Comment: I didn't understand. You want the HTML and CSS of the page? Or you need how to that in electron? Because in the second case you only have to create a BrowserWindow at the application start with the HTML code for the loader. When you know that your app is ready, close the BrowserWindow or load the new URL...

Comment: The second and that makes sense. I didn't know if it was an option from within electron or just a separate browser window. With a separate browser window i take it the assets from the main window (which is closed) will still continue to load?

Comment: You can manage it as you want :) You can make all in the same BrowserWindow and change page when you have the ready signal or you can open 2 different BrowserWindow, it depends from what kind of feature yoyr BrowserWindow(s) have to have